# most efficient way in c# to parse a large Xml string (to expand DTD references, add new lines etc)

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, dtd, xmlreader

I have an interface that provides large Xml strings that are valid XML but may not be in standard form (say missing prefix for default namespace specified) or are without any line-endings or need expansion of entities in in-lined DTD. Basically I need to parse these strings with standard Xml parser that can handle in-lined DTD definitions. This string data can be anywhere from few characters to giga bytes.

At present I am using following code (and such simple parsing seems to be able to fix issues that I mentioned above):

```
              XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(LargeXmlString);

                var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Indent = true;
                settings.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
                //more settings

                StringBuilder parsedOutput = new StringBuilder();
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter =       
                          XmlWriter.Create(parsedOutput, settings))
                {
                    doc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
                }
```

While this is easy to use, I am not sure how good/bad it is compared to using some other .net xml parsing classes like XmlReader/XmlTextReader or XmlDocument etc?

What is the best/most efficient way of doing this using .net/c# supported classes (possibly without writing lot of new code)?

thanks for your help

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Catalogue    xmlns="http://www.somewhere.org/BookCatalogue" xmlns:cat="http://www.somewhere.org/BookCatalogue" xmlns:html="http://www.somewhere.org/HTMLCatalogue" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.somewhere.org/BookCatalogue                         txjsgen14.txt"><cat:Magazine><Title>Natural Health</Title><Author>October</Author><Date>December, 1999</Date><Volume>12</Volume>.....`
```

gets converted to

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cat:Catalogue xmlns="http://www.somewhere.org/BookCatalogue" xmlns:cat="http://www.somewhere.org/BookCatalogue" xmlns:html="http://www.somewhere.org/HTMLCatalogue" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.somewhere.org/BookCatalogue                         txjsgen14.txt">
  <cat:Magazine>
    <cat:Title>Natural Health</cat:Title>
    <cat:Author>October</cat:Author>
    <cat:Date>December, 1999</cat:Date>
    <cat:Volume>12</cat:Volume>
    <cat:htmlTable>.....`
```

Note the addition of cat prefix to Title and other elements based on name space declarations

Thank you all for your responses.

@ Enigmativity 
Sorry for the confusion i created in the confusion. 
Actually, i only need a string to string conversion where first string has not-so-proper XML which is not properly formatted, not expanding DTD entities, not having line delimeters and may be missing prefixes etc. While the second string should have fixed all of these things.
Now if some component (say XmlReader) can take first string as argument and make it canonical/properly formatted/expanded XML and return as a string then all I need is one component.  In example above, the parsing is done by XDocument and the formatting is done by XmlWriter. and I am not even sure of who does the expansion of entities, the parser or the XmlWriter. Probably the writer.

For the time being I will try to use a combination of XmReader and XmlWriter, where XmlReader reads the first string and the XmlWriter writes the formated one (as specified by the XmlWriterSettings used for the XmlWriter). Let me know if there is any better approach.

Comment: `XmlReader` is a streaming parser, and what everything else is built on. It will be less memory intensive to use that directly.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. You're asking about parsing, yet your code shows writing. Then you pop in a snippit of XML and ask us to note the addition of cat prefixes, but then don't ask us anything about it. Can you please fix your question?

Comment: Regarding the `cat` prefix being added - that's because the default namespace and the `cat` namspace both use the same URI - ` xmlns="http://www.somewhere.org/BookCatalogue" xmlns:cat="http://www.somewhere.org/BookCatalogue"`. If you change one to something unique then the addition of the `cat` prefix doesn't happen.

Comment: If your XML is potentially gigabytes in size, it's probably unwise to load the entire XML string into memory before processing it.

Comment: @ Charles Mager,     True, so i cannot use the XDocument the way I described above. Instead there should be a two component collaboration in read loop where one reads the xml, the other writes/appends to converted xml string. I am going to try XmlReader and XmlWriter combination for same. Anything better?.        Note that I already have one potentially large string in memory that I read from database. So for a possible 2 GB string, I will write another 2GB converted string but will save any overhead of XDocument's node-stack etc.

Comment: @Cory Nelson, Thanks Cory, I am going to try XmlReader/XmlWriter combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do essentially what you have in your example, but with `XmlReader`:

```
XmlReader xmlReader = ...;

using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = ...)
{
    xmlWriter.WriteNode(reader, true);
}
```

This will be the most efficient way -- streaming the document node by node vs. reading the entire thing into memory before writing it out.

Answer (score 0):

For large xml always use XmlReader to prevent out of memory errors.  The code below uses xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<cat:Catalogue xmlns=\"http://www.somewhere.org/BookCatalogue\" xmlns:cat=\"http://www.somewhere.org/BookCatalogue\" xmlns:html=\"http://www.somewhere.org/HTMLCatalogue\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.somewhere.org/BookCatalogue                         txjsgen14.txt\">" +
                  "<cat:Magazine>" +
                    "<cat:Title>Natural Health</cat:Title>" +
                    "<cat:Author>October</cat:Author>" +
                    "<cat:Date>December, 1999</cat:Date>" +
                    "<cat:Volume>12</cat:Volume>" +
                    "<cat:htmlTable>" +
                    "</cat:htmlTable>" +
                  "</cat:Magazine>" +
                  "<cat:Magazine>" +
                    "<cat:Title>Natural Health</cat:Title>" +
                    "<cat:Author>October</cat:Author>" +
                    "<cat:Date>December, 1999</cat:Date>" +
                    "<cat:Volume>12</cat:Volume>" +
                    "<cat:htmlTable>" +
                    "</cat:htmlTable>" +
                  "</cat:Magazine>" +
                "</cat:Catalogue>";
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);

            xReader.MoveToContent();
            XNamespace ns = xReader.LookupNamespace(xReader.Prefix);


            while (!xReader.EOF)
            {
                if (xReader.LocalName != "Magazine")
                {
                    xReader.ReadToFollowing("Magazine", ns.NamespaceName);
                }
                if(!xReader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement magazine = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(xReader);
                    string title = (string)magazine.Element(ns + "Title");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jdweng, I will try it, but as I do not need to do anything with those nodes, I will try to use a combination of XmReader and XmlWriter, where one reads and other writes and only difference is the settings used for writer. Let me know if you have any other idea.

Comment: Just tried XmlReader/writer combination, it works to reproduce the string as it is and failed to even fix the format of the XML that doesn't have proper line ending and indentation, even though i provided settings for indentation. So seems the XDocument parsing is fixing most of the format, entity expansion and prefixing etc (which i need).

Comment: Spacing is not an xml requirement so it is not considered an error.